# Java- AWT Applets- How to change the size of a shape on my program?

Tags: java, applet, awt

[image: My program]

This program is designed to take a shape decided by the user and change the size of it based on input.

*I have two issues.* One is that the user will have to input it as a string yet the size value is an integer. If I convert integer to string it will give me an null exception when converting.  (java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)Exception).)

The other problem is that I do not know what to add in the actionPerfomed method. Since all of the information only needs to go to the paint method. How can I transfer the integer value into the Paint method.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.applet.Applet;


public class ChangeSize extends Applet
    implements ActionListener
{
    Button bttn1 = new Button ("Circle");
    Button bttn2 = new Button ("Square");
    Button bttn3 = new Button ("Triangle");
    Button bttn4 = new Button ("Rectangle");

    Label lab1; // text within applet
    TextField t1; // where user inputs text
    String input;

    int choice;

    public void init ()
    {
        this.setSize (500, 300);

        setBackground (Color.lightGray);

        lab1 = new Label ("Insert the size of the shape:");
        //int Size = Integer.parseInt (input);
        add (lab1);
        t1 = new TextField ();
        add (t1);

        bttn1.addActionListener (this); // circle button
        bttn2.addActionListener (this); // square button
        bttn3.addActionListener (this); // triangle button
        bttn4.addActionListener (this); // rectangle button

        add (bttn1);
        add (bttn2);
        add (bttn3);
        add (bttn4);

    }
    public void paint (Graphics g)
    {
        int xpoints[] = {25, 145, 25, 145, 25}; \
        int ypoints[] = {25, 25, 145, 145, 25};
        int npoints = 5;

        switch (choice)
        {
            case 1:
                if (choice == 1)
                    g.setColor (Color.red);
                g.fillOval (30, 40, 20, 20); // I want it to be (30,40, 20, size). Instead


            case 2:
                if (choice == 2)
                    g.fillRect (20, 40, 100, 100);
            case 3:
                if (choice == 3)
                    g.fillPolygon (xpoints, ypoints, npoints);
            case 4:
                if (choice == 4)
                    g.fillRect (20, 40, 50, 100);

                break;
        }

        showStatus ("Please seclect an option.");
    }
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent evt)
    {
        if (evt.getSource () == bttn1)
            choice = 1;
        else if (evt.getSource () == bttn2)
            choice = 2;
        else if (evt.getSource () == bttn3)
            choice = 3;
        else if (evt.getSource () == bttn4)
            choice = 4;

          Size = t1.getText ();

          // I dont know what to put here

        repaint ();
    }

}
```

Comment: Why AWT in 2013?  Swing is the GUI toolkit to use in the (start of) the 3rd millennium. `this.setSize (500, 300);`  Don't do that in an applet (whether `Applet` ***or*** `JApplet`), the size is set in HTML (probably written by JavaScript).

Answer (score 2):

You're close to a solution and your comment, `// I want it to be (30,40, 20, size). Instead`
 holds the key.

- Give your application an int class field or fields to hold your drawing size.
- use that size to set the shape's size in your painting routine.
- Allow the user to change the sizes in the actionPerformed method.
- The text you get will be a String, and you will need to parse this into an int before you can use it via the `Integer.parseInt(...)` method.

Regarding:

> I have two issues. One is that the user will have to input it as a string yet the size value is an integer. If I convert integer to string it will give me an null exception when converting. (java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)Exception).)

The problem is where you're trying to parse the int. You're doing it in the init method which is the method that creates and builds the applet, which is *way* before the user has had time to add input into the text field. It would be much better to parse in the actionPerformed method.